# Speech Recognition feedback loop

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am working on a speech recognition system to talk with my computer. Now I have my computer audio output set to a surround sound system. This has caused problems for the recognition system. For example when I say "test" to see if its online, the system responds with "test complete". The microphone hears the "test complete" and goes into an infinite loop of saying test complete. My question is, Is there anyway to stop the program from listening when it is speaking and then start listening again after it has finished speaking? I was thinking of maybe someway making sure it responds only to my voice. I am open to any suggestions.

My code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace SpeechRecog
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Choices onoff = new Choices();
    private Choices recChoices = new Choices();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine RE = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine LRE = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ss.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);

    }

    private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RE.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnDisable.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Choices commands = new Choices();        
        commands.Add(new string[] { "Say Hello", "Test","What's my name", "yahoo", "Thank you", "Hey", "Facebook", "Music", "Lock", "Time"});
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(commands);
        Grammar Grammar = new Grammar(gb);
        RE.LoadGrammarAsync(Grammar);
        RE.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        RE.SpeechRecognized += RE_SpeechRecognized;




    }

    private void LRE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text.Equals("Hey")) ;
        {
            RE.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        } }

    public string time()
    { DateTime n = DateTime.Now;
        string o = n.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
            return o;
            }

    private void RE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        string speech = e.Result.Text;




        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "Test":
                ss.SpeakAsync("Test Complete");
                break;
            case "Say Hello":
            case "Introduce yourself":
                ss.SpeakAsync("My name is Friday. I was designed to simplify daily life. How can I assist you today?");
                break;
            case "What's my name":
                ss.SpeakAsync("Arno");
                break;
            case "yahoo":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.yahoo.com");
                break;
            case "Facebook":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.Facebook.com");
                break;
            case "Music":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iTunes.exe");
                break;
            case "Lock":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Rundll32.exe", "User32.dll,LockWorkStation");
                break;
            case "Thank You":

                break;
            case "Time":
                ss.Speak(time());
                break;





                    }
    }

    private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RE.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnDisable.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not familiar with the speech namespace, but looking at the doc, ```SpeechSynthesizer``` has a [SpeakCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event that is raised when speaking is completed. You could mute the mic, and hook up a listener that un-mutes it again when the event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RecognizeAsyncCancel()` or [RecognizeAsyncStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasyncstop(v=vs.110).aspx)()

```
private void RE_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    RE.recognizer.RecognizeAsyncStop();
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378412(v=office.14).aspx):

> To stop an asynchronous recognition
>   operation, use the RecognizeAsyncCancel() or RecognizeAsyncStop()
>   methods. You can pause a running SpeechRecognitionEngine instance to
>   update its configuration or to load and unload grammars using one of
>   the RequestRecognizerUpdate() methods. The SpeechRecognitionEngine can
>   perform an additional mode of recognition (called emulation) during
>   which it accepts text, rather than speech, as input. Emulated
>   recognition can be useful for debugging grammars. The speech
>   recognizer raises the SpeechDetected, SpeechHypothesized,
>   SpeechRecognitionRejected, and SpeechRecognized events as if the
>   recognition operation is not emulated. To initiate emulated
>   recognition, call one of the EmulateRecognize() or
>   EmulateRecognizeAsync() methods and pass in text or an array of words
>   for which you want to perform emulated recognition.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that simple! Thank you. Do you know of anyway to apply that to all of the cases I have? Or do I have to use the RecognizeAsyncStop on each one?